# Declaring Hibernate event listeners in a JPA environment

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, events, listener

Hy guys,

I am working on a project developed in Java EE 5 environment. I want to know how I can declare a Hibernate event listener so that I can be informed when CRUD operation are performed.

I've read that I must  declare in the Hibernate configuration file `*cfg.xml` something like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        ...
        <event type="load">
            <listener class="com.eg.MyLoadListener"/>
            <listener class="org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener"/>
        </event>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The problem is I don't have such a file in the project. We are using JPA (with Hibernate as the underlying implementation). Do you know if I need to create that specific file? If yes where should I put it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit">
        ...
        <snip/>
        ...
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.load" value="com.eg.MyLoadListener,org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener"/>    
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In the [Hibernate EntityManager docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html) look at "Table 2.1. Hibernate Entity Manager specific properties" for all applicable properties.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using annotations? If so, you can use the [`@EntityListeners`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityListeners.html) annotation to do that, like so:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AbstractEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    ...
}
```

Your entity listener class could look like this:

```
public class AbstractEntityListener {

    /**
     * Set creation and lastUpdated date of the entity.
     * 
     * @param entity {@link AbstractEntity}
     */
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void setDate(final AbstractEntity entity) {
        final Date now = new Date();
        entity.setModified(now);
    }

}
```

There are different annotations available to catch different events, like [`@PrePersist`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html), [`@PreUpdate`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html), [`@PostLoad`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html), etc.

Comment: No, the question is actually about where to put hibernate specific config when using JPA.

Comment: @ewernli: "I want to know how I can declare a Hibernate event listener so that I can be informed when CRUD operation are performed." My answer solves the problem without any cumbersome Hibernate stunts, I think.

Comment: I've undeleted my old answer so that you can see the answer from the OP. For some reason he doesn't want to use entity listener. I share you opinion otherwise.

Comment: @ewernli: Ah, I see! Makes sense now. Still, IMHO the OP should rather resolve his issues with the JPA entity listeners instead of doing anything crazy. +1 for your answer!

Comment: @ewernli & @Henning - You can do much more powerful operations using Hibernate entity listeners compared with JPA event listeners.  It may be that he needs this extra functionality.

Comment: @Henning - The question is also generic, so someone looking for information on custom hibernate listeners configuration within a JPA environment may find it useful. Some listeners JPA does not support.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can also specify this with annotations on the callback methods. Either embed them in the entity itself, or in a separate class, called an entity listener. Here is a snippet taken from the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/listeners.html):

```
@Entity 
@EntityListeners(class=Audit.class)
public class Cat {

    @Id private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @PostLoad
    public void calculateAge() {
       ...
    }
}

public class LastUpdateListener {

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void setLastUpdate(Cat o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I guess you can also specify that in the XML config. But annotation are more convenient in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks,

But I think these are the JPA entity listeners. I tried with these ones and I am encountering some issues. I want to try directly with Hibernate event listeners.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you can specific the usual `hibnerate.cfg.xml` as a property `hibernate.ejb.cfgfile`.

> You may also define all your hibernate
>   configuration in the usual Hibernate
>   way: within a hibernate.xfg.xml file.
>   You must tell the JPA implementation
>   to use this configuration file through
>   the hibernate.ejb.cfgfile property.

See [this](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2007/07/06/co-existence-with-hibernate-jpa-and-ejb3/) post or [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2377634) one.

```
<persistence>
 <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Note that I never use that personally.